# kafka connect ignores fields in message to jdbc postgres

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka, protocol-buffers, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to set up a Kafka Connect to copy data from the topic (in Protobuf) to PostgreSQL db.
I set it up, and it's working but half of the fields are being completely ignored, without any error, simply missing in the db.
Below is my connector, and in the db only the fields value, isSomething, physicalType and key are present.
missing fields are all different types (string - text, int64, custom types which i'd like as a string).

```
{
    "schema.registry.url": "http://schema-registry:8081",
    "name": "JdbcSinkConnectorConnector_0",
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
    "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
    "key.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://schema-registry:8081",
    "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.protobuf.ProtobufConverter",
    "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://schema-registry:8081",
    "value.converter.schemas.enable": true,
    "topics": "schema.data.normalized",
    "confluent.controlcenter.schema.registry.url": "http://schema-registry:8081",
    "connection.url": "jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/db",
    "connection.user": "postgres",
    "connection.password": "a",
    "dialect.name": "PostgreSqlDatabaseDialect",
    "pk.mode": "record_key",
    "pk.fields": "key",
    "auto.create": true,
    "auto.evolve": true,
    "table.name.format": "app.TestTable",
    "fields.whitelist": "fieldA,created,unitSymbol,unitMultiplier,timeStamp,value,validForStart,validForEnd,isSomething,physicalType",
    "transforms": "RenameField",
    "transforms.RenameField.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ReplaceField$Value",
    "transforms.RenameField.renames": "created:created_timestamp"
}
```

```
syntax = "proto3";
package xxx;

import "identified_object.proto";
import "unit_symbol.proto";
import "unit_multiplier.proto";

option java_multiple_files = true;

message XxxMessage {
  .IdentifiedObject id = 1;
  .IdentifiedObject environmental_data_provider = 2;
  string fieldA = 3;
  int64 created = 4;
  .UnitSymbol unit_symbol = 5;
  .UnitMultiplier unit_multiplier = 6;
  int64 time_stamp = 7;
  float value = 8;
  int64 valid_for_start = 9;
  int64 valid_for_end = 10;
  bool isSomething = 11;
  string physicalType = 12;
}
```

Example message:

```
{
  "id": {
    "aliasName": "",
    "description": "",
    "mRid": "8f90016b-7f2c-4172-a52a-bd6caae95020",
    "name": ""
  },
  "environmentalDataProvider": {
    "aliasName": "",
    "description": "",
    "mRid": "408851cf-d0d5-43fe-a8cf-e234583aa7ae",
    "name": "...."
  },
  "fieldA": "rb771347-3691-4920-88af-b2b8caffdea1",
  "created": "1664469000000",
  "unitSymbol": "UNIT_SYMBOL_METER_Per_SEC",
  "unitMultiplier": "UNIT_MULTIPLIER_UNSPECIFIED",
  "timeStamp": "1664857800000",
  "value": 4.2018013,
  "validForStart": "1664857800000",
  "validForEnd": "1664858700000",
  "isSomething": true,
  "physicalType": "typeA"
}
```

edit: added proto schema and example message

Comment: Please share your proto schema and the actual data in the topic (output from `kafka-protobuf-console-consumer`)

Comment: added proto schema and the message from the topic which should be imported.
what is kafka-protobuf-console-consumer? Right now i have no consumers on this topic, i just want to import the data into the db (consumers will be added later)

Comment: Kafka Connect acts as a consumer... [`kafka-protobuf-console-consumer`](https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/blob/master/bin/kafka-protobuf-console-consumer) is a script that is installed as part of Confluent Platform and will help you debug the events in the actual topic

Comment: _"only the fields value, isSomething, physicalType and key are present"_ - Because those literally map to the same names in the schema... `validForStart` in the JSON doesn't map to `valid_for_start`, for example. You cannot mix `snake_case` and `camelCase`. Also, I don't think JDBC Connector natively supports nested objects.

Comment: Just now noticed it :)
the published message is a .net object created by googles protobuf library based on that protobuf definition, so i assumed it should all be automatically recognized.
can i solve it with some transform?
and my next step was to put that in my own table with different names, how could i do that?